# Autofit text in merged rows in Excel interop objects. C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a method that writes data in excel, but there are parts that have a lot of text and the method wrap the text into the column but I can´t do it in the rows because they are merged. So i get something like this:

[image]

And I need to get it like This:

[image]

Is there a way to do it by code? Using Interop Objects. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Merged cells are evil. Why would you need them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is correct or not, but I've come up with the following solution. The idea is the following:

1. remember rows count
2. calculate total height of all rows in merged area
3. calculate percentage of every row according to total height
4. unmerge cells
5. autofit rows
6. remember the height of first row (i.e. data row) - a *new* height
7. **main**: apply percentage (on stage 3) to *new* height
8. merge cells back (with the help of rows count on stage 1)

As you can see, this method is universal - i.e. it will work on any rows count in merged area and it will honor the previous ratio of each row according to new height. You can download [sample workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCk0fHchZLrhT5_8BS) with code.

**VBA**

```
Sub Test()
    Call AutoFitMergedCells(Range("D11"))
End Sub

Sub AutoFitMergedCells(cell As Range)

    Dim dOldHeight#, dNewHeight#, dPercent#, arow, addr, rows_count
    Dim dicCells As New Dictionary, dicHeights As New Dictionary

    '// turn off flickering
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With cell

        '// remember rows count for merging cells back
        rows_count = .MergeArea.Count

        '// every dictionary entry holds following info:
        '// 1) original height of all rows in merged cells
        '// 2) percentage of row's height to height of all rows in merged area
        For Each arow In .MergeArea.Rows
            With arow.Cells(1)
                Set dicHeights = New Dictionary
                dicHeights("height") = .RowHeight
                dicHeights("percent") = 0
                dicCells.Add Key:=.Address(0, 0), Item:=dicHeights
            End With
        Next

        '// total height of all rows
        For Each addr In dicCells.Keys()
            dOldHeight = dOldHeight + dicCells(addr)("height")
        Next

        '// update the percentage of every row
        For Each addr In dicCells.Keys()
            dicCells(addr)("percent") = dicCells(addr)("height") / dOldHeight
        Next

        .UnMerge
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        '// remember new height
        dNewHeight = .RowHeight

        '// this applies percentage of previous row's height to new height
        For Each addr In dicCells.Keys()
            Range(addr).EntireRow.RowHeight = dicCells(addr)("percent") * dNewHeight
        Next

        '// merge back
        .Resize(rows_count).Merge

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

#### UPDATE

**C#**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void ProcessMergedCells()
{

    var xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = false, ScreenUpdating = false };
    // get Excel process in order to kill it after the work is done
    var xlHandle = new IntPtr(xlApp.Hwnd);
    var xlProc = Process
                 .GetProcesses()
                 .First(p => p.MainWindowHandle == xlHandle);
    var book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\AutoFitMergedCells.xlsm");
    var sheet = book.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

    // obtain merged cells any way you like
    // here I just populate array with arbitrary cells
    var merged_ranges = new Excel.Range[]
    {
        sheet.Range["D11"],
        sheet.Range["D13"]
    };

    // process merged cells
    foreach(var merged_range in merged_ranges)
    {
        AutoFitMergedCells(merged_range);
    }

    // quit with saving
    book.Close(SaveChanges: true);
    xlApp.Quit();

    // clean up
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

    // kill Excel for sure
    xlProc.Kill();

}

private void AutoFitMergedCells(Excel.Range merged_range)
{

    double dOldHeight = 0d, dNewHeight = 0d;
    var dicCells = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>();

    // remember rows count for merging cells back
    int rows_count = merged_range.MergeArea.Count;

    // every dictionary entry holds following info:
    // 1) original height of all rows in merged cells
    // 2) percentage of row's height to height of all rows in merged area
    foreach (Excel.Range the_row in merged_range.MergeArea.Rows)
    {
        // we need only top-left cell
        var first_cell = the_row.Cells[1];
        var dicHeights = new Dictionary<string, double>
        {
            ["height"] = first_cell.RowHeight,
            ["percent"] = 0d
        };
        dicCells[first_cell.Address[0, 0]] = dicHeights;
    }

    // total height of all rows
    foreach (string addr in dicCells.Keys)
        dOldHeight += dicCells[addr]["height"];

    // update the percentage of every row
    foreach (string addr in dicCells.Keys)
        dicCells[addr]["percent"] = dicCells[addr]["height"] / dOldHeight;

    // unmerge range and autofit
    merged_range.UnMerge();
    merged_range.EntireRow.AutoFit();

    // remember new height
    dNewHeight = merged_range.RowHeight;

    // this applies percentage of previous row's height to new height
    var sheet = merged_range.Parent;
    foreach (string addr in dicCells.Keys)
        sheet.Range[addr].EntireRow.RowHeight = dicCells[addr]["percent"] * dNewHeight;

    // merge back
    merged_range.Resize[rows_count].Merge();

}
```

Comment: Very cool...  and for the OP's benefit, there are VB.net to C# translators everywhere, even within Visual Studio itself.

Comment: @Hambone Oops! OP needs C#  I will translate the code a bit later 

Comment: It's a good solution.  Worst case, he can package it in VB project and call it from his C# project.  I wouldn't -- I'd translate it -- but that's the most difficult thing he would have to do to get this to work, which is not that bad

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall where I saw this, but I once saw a hack to accomplish this.  In a nutshell, you take the text in question from the merged cell, paste it into a non-merged cell in the same column and do an autofit on that one cell to see how tall it should be.  Then you take that height of the safe cell and manually set it to each of the merged rows, dividing by the total number of rows that were merged.

It's ugly, but it does work.  In your example, if it's always two rows, that makes it a lot easier because you can always divide by two and increment the row count by two.  If not, you just need to factor that in.  Assuming C1 is our "safe cell," it would looks something like this:

```
Excel.Range testCell = ws.Cells[1, 3];
testCell.WrapText = true;

for (int row = 11; row < ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; row += 2)
{
    testCell.Value2 = ws.Cells[row, 4].Value2;
    testCell.Rows.AutoFit();
    ws.Range[string.Format("{0}:{1}", row, row + 1)].RowHeight = testCell.RowHeight / 2;
}
```